# paypal orders go to abandoned orders in opencart

Tags: e-commerce, paypal, opencart

I am using opencart and when I test payment with paypal/credit card with paypal standard the payment occurs but it goes into abandoned orders in opencart! why is this happening? I tried in the open cart forum for solutions but there was no solution!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any kind of directory protection on the open cart folder (ie are you testing and used a user/pass to access the folder)? if so, this is the issue, and you will need to remove that as your cart will require the IPN to have access to the site (which it wont if you have the password protection)